# ¿How can I fix my main disk? (problem with Ubuntu 19.04 EFI and Windows 7)

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, external-hdd

I have been trying to install **Ubuntu 19.04** together with Windows from a USB in an **Acer Aspire Z3771 with Intel Core i3–2120 CPU @ 3.30 GHz and 6 GB of RAM on an external disk** (to avoid problems with my internal disk). Before then I had installed **Ubuntu 15.04** and everything had worked fine except that since it's an old version I couldn't do anything (I couldn't update the packages) so that's why I decided to install a newer version.

When I installed the old version, I made a primary partition for */boot* with 2GB. Then I made three logical partitions; one for *swap*, with 12GB, as I've been told that it should have twice the RAM capacity; one for */home* with 436 GB; and another for */(root)* with 50 GB. In both installation processes, I made the exact same partitions (except for the **EFI partition** in **Ubuntu 19.04**) and both times I followed the installation process (i.e. I didn't have the previously made partitions, but I made them at the time of installation).

The problem arose (I think) when the installer for **Ubuntu 19.04** asked if I wanted to proceed to install
without using an EFI partition "because if you did so you probably wouldn't be able to boot the operating system" (despite having done it without **EFI partition** with **Ubuntu 15.04**). That message
of warning left me wondering "What if I can't access my **Windows 7** disk later because I can't use the **Ubuntu GRUB**?" So I decided to make the **EFI partition** fearing I would lose access to the **Windows 7** disk. The irony is that this is exactly what happened when doing this with an **EFI partition**: I almost lost access to my hard drive with Windows 7; and I say almost because now I can only boot **Windows 7** from the **boot menu** that appears when I just start the PC.

If I try to start Ubuntu, I get a **GRUB prompt** —which I don't know how to use—. Also, I get disk dump descriptions on the disk that has **Windows 7**. Does it mean it is damaged?

How can I reboot from my **Windows 7** disk, as I did before?

---

Anyway I would like someone to help me get Ubuntu 19.04 on my external hard drive without modifying anything on my other drive (the internal one with Windows 7).

Comment: Una nota, Ricardo: la version Ubuntu 19.04 esta ya caducada y no tiene mantenimiento. Le recomiendo ponerse al dia con Ubuntu 19.10, o Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, o en un mes o asi, con Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Entendido, buscaré la 18.04 LTS :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es ir al administror de particiones de Windows 7(no recuerdo bien como se llama) y eliminar las particiones de ubuntu(solo dejar la de windows), de esta forma estarias como "borrando" ubuntu y el grub si no me equivoco.(deberias borrar las particiones "/","/boot", swap y /home)
De esta forma estarías como antes de instalar el ubuntu en tu equipo.(no estoy muy segudo de esto)

Una vez hecho esto puedes crear nuevamente las particiones en la instalación de ubuntu(busca algun tutorial de como instalarlo correctamente,por si me olvido de algo), pero con "/home", "/" y el "swap" deberia alcanzarte para iniciar el grub y escoger entre windows y ubuntu(yo tengo instalado de esa forma mi equipo, y tengo windows 10+Lubuntu)

**ADVERTENCIA**: no borres la partición de windows ni las particiones extras a las que nombré(solamente borra esas 4 de arriba),ya que podrías a llegar perder el acceso a windows tambien.

PD: te dejo la guia que siempre uso para instalar windows con linux:

https://www.xataka.com/basics/como-instalar-linux-a-windows-10-ordenador

Comment: Gracias, trataré de borrar estas particiones que has mencionado, aunque temo que la otra partición (la del EFI) pueda meterme en problemas; no sé si al haber hecho lo de la partición EFI, Ubuntu tal vez haya quitado la capacidad de arranque de mi otro disco —es decir, puedo arrancar Windows 7, pero no de la manera usual—. Y respecto a Ubuntu, simplemente no quedó instalado. (jaja no puedo creer lo torpe que soy instalando Ubuntu, ya me compliqué demasiado).